# LAPACK from Pytrilinos for least-squares

Tags: sparse-matrix, solver, lapack, least-squares, trilinos

I'm trying to solve a large sparse 30,000x1,000 matrix using the a LAPACK solver in the Trilinos package. My goal is to minimise computation time however this Lapack solver only takes square matrices. So I'm manually converting my non-square matrix (A) into a square matrix by multiplying by its transpose, essentially solving the system like so:

(A<sup>T</sup>*A)x = A<sup>T</sup>*b

What is making my solve slow are the matrix multiplications by A<sup>T</sup> steps.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: If the problem is sparse, you may want to check about support for sparse solvers in this environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly compute the QR-decomposition ([wikipedia-link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition)) and use that to solve your least squares problem.
This way you don't have to compute the matrix product `A^T A`.

There are multiple LAPACK routines for the computation of QR-decompositions, e.g. `gels` is a driver routine for general matrices ([intel-link](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/_gels.htm)).

I must say that I don't know if Trilinos supplies that routine but it is a standard LAPACK routine.